# IN HTML5 required and placeholder are not working in IE8

Tags: html, validation

```
<form action="example.php">  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" placeholder="Enter your name " required>  <input type="submit"></form>
```

its working on mozilla firefox , chrome , IE9-10 but its not working IE8 and lower .

Please help me to fix this .
Thanks 
gopi

Comment: The placeholder question is a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296602/html-form-placeholder-not-working-in-ie-8

Comment: The question about the required attribute is also a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959955/html5-input-validation-doesnt-work-in-ie8